# Matic Mumbai deployment failed at migration with Replay-Protected (EIP-155) error

Tags: polygon, matic

I'm looking to deploy dApp onto Polygon's Matic Mumbai test network, but I keep getting errors. Contracts deploy well on all Ethereum networks and I've made sure to have some MATIC (just in case even though it's not asking for any). Here's what I get:

```
Compiling your contracts...
=============================
```

all good no issues. then starts migration as per usual:

```
  Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'matic'
> Network id:      80001
> Block gas limit: 20000000 (0x1312d00)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- only replay-protected (EIP-155) transactions allowed over RPC.
```

in terminal i'm following their "how to" guide verbatim:

Truffle:

```
matic: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rpc-mumbai.matic.today`),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
    },
```

and terminal:

```
truffle migrate --network matic
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong and how to fix the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using Matic Vigil or another RPC provider?

Comment: No I have not. I will need to read more about Vigil. I was, to the best of my ability trying to follow Polygon docs on how to do it.

Comment: If it worked using another RPC provider do let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, and thanks to the folks here:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3913

I figured out that I just needed to update this NPM package:

```
"truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17"
```

To be:

```
"@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.4.0"
```